# Block user going back in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view In navigationController.When user presses back button I need to check is the data the he chooses in view right.If it is I allow him to go back , if not I show notification that he did a mistake and allow him to stay in this view and don't allow to go back.I tried to do this in viewWillDisappear but my code is not working in a right way.How I can organize such thing?

Comment: how to check data is correct in your code through web or local ?

Comment: Do you have custom back button? if yes then Why don't you put logic in your BackButton Action.

Comment: How you written code to go back: using segue or using popviewcontroller

Comment: I don't have custom back button.Data is local.User just choosing cells that is NSSet , NSSet count must not be more then constant number.I didn't write any code to go back , all is automatically doing by stroryboard.

Comment: use the segue name to move after your condition get satisfied.

Comment: You can hide the back button as soon as you enter in the view (viewDidLoad) and make it appear again when the data in the view is correctly filled/chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be implementing your own custom back button. Add the following code to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
```

and your selector method would  be-

```
- (void) back:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

        if(/*your condition satisfy*/) {
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else {
          /** Popup your alert here */
        }

    }
```

Comment: where u check the condition , can you modify the answer based on question

Comment: On the - (void) back:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender method he can check user data & make decision if he allow user to go back.

Comment: if you modify the answer it will useful for questioner